# PHP: Regex for getting directions in an address

Tags: php, regex

I have this sample address:

> 405 W 1st Street South west #910

And I have this regex expression to extract the possibilities of an address that has the word North, South, West, East, North East, North West, South East, South West:

```
preg_match_all("/(?:(?:north|south)(?:[ ](?:east|west))?|east|west)/i", $address, $match);
```

Now if we look at the address string above, "W" is considered as West, so there could even be N, S, NW, NE, SE, SW, E, W. So we also need to extract these.

I'm not too good at regular expressions, hope you could help? Thanks!

Comment: No idea what exactly you need, but try [`'~\b(?:north|south)(?:\h*(?:east|west))?\b|\b(?:east|west|[NS][WE]?|[EW])\b~i'`](https://regex101.com/r/rG0cH6/2).

Comment: I'd go with @WiktorStribiżew's answer. Updated on [version 3](https://regex101.com/r/rG0cH6/3) to contain a few more cases (things that should fully match, things that should partially match, things that should not match).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(?:north|south)(?:\h*(?:east|west))?\b|\b(?:east|west|[NS][WE]?|[EW])\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rG0cH6/3)

*Explanation*:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?:north|south)` - either `north` or `south`
- `(?:\h*(?:east|west))?` - one or zero occurrences of zero or more horizontal whitespaces (`\h*`)  followed with either `east` or `west`
- `\b` - trailing word boundary
- `|` - or...
- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?:east|west|[NS][WE]?|[EW])` - either `east`, `west`, `N`, `NW`, `NE`, `S`, `SW`, `SE`
- `\b` - trailing word boundary